# How to display in the reading pane the most recent email, sent or not, of a conversation when clicking a conversation in the Outlook 2010 inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-web-access

If, in my *inbox*, I click a conversation in the *messages pane*, even if I have since sent a reply, Outlook 2010 will display the most recently *received* email in the *reading pane*.  I want it to display the most recently *sent or received* email in the conversation.

The Outlook Web App shows the entire conversation in the *reading pane*, with the most recent email active (unfolded), even if it was *sent*.  Even this would be an acceptable alternative (if not preferable).

Note that Outlook 2010 is already in conversation view and *does* show the sent messages when the conversation is expanded.

**Edit:** I was able to replicate this somewhat by making a search folder (see below). It would still be nice to get it to work on the inbox.

**Edit 2:** *Partial Solution using a Search Folder*:

I was able to make a search folder which included all mail not in Deleted Items, grouped by conversation and sorted by date. In this folder, when I click on a conversation, the most recent email, *sent or received*, displays in the reading pane. I also favorited the folder for more prominent display, and used NBO's method for making Outlook start in it. This is the exact (nearly, see caveat below) functionality that I want, only in the Inbox.

***Caveat***

Moving conversations functions differently in search folders than in the Inbox. In the Inbox, moving the conversation to another folder only moves the *received** emails. In search folders, all matched* emails (including *sent* emails) are moved.

**- I haven't thoroughly tested the conditions for when the emails are moved, so more or less of them may be moved than indicated above.*

Comment: It took me forever to figure this out. In Outlook 2013 (at least), when you create the Search Folder, the *Show as Conversations* checkbox in the View ribbon is grayed out. Instead, you have to go to **View Settings** (same ribbon), then **Group By...**, uncheck *Automatically group according to arrangement*, and then under *Group items by*, choose **Conversation**. Now the *Show as Conversations* checkbox is checked.

Comment: Same issue with Outlook 2016. Pretty annoying ...

Answer (score 4):

It's a feature, not a bug.

Outlook shows the messages in the *current* folder, and if you check the option to "Show Messages from Other Folders", it will also show them in the conversation thread, *but* will only select by default the last from *this* folder.

This may be helpful: Under the View tab → Conversation Settings, set all options to "Always expand", and to indent. At least it's visible that there is a newer message you sent.

The other option as you commented is to create a Search folder to include all inbox and sent items and set it as the starting folder for outlook going to "file" - "Options" - "Advanced" and modifying Outlook start and Exit - see screenshots:
[image]
[image: Favorites]

Comment: I have seen the "Always Expand" option, and this is nice on small conversations, but is incredibly annoying on large ones. I understand the reasoning why it is only showing me the most recent message in my current folder, but the implementation of the conversation feature is inconsistent between Outlook and OWA.

Comment: I do like the sound of your rules based solution. Would you mind elaborating on it a bit? Note that if it involves moving both _sent and received_ messages into the same folder, that is definitely not ideal. I'll expand the description of my search folder solution above.

Comment: With your clarification it is now easy - just make the search folder the starting folder - I'll add images in post above

Comment: That's great. I upvoted your answer and updated the body of the question to reflect this. As this is just a workaround (though a very effective one), I'm going to leave the question open for now. If no one provides a proper solution before the last day of the bounty, I'll award it to you.

Comment: I spoke too soon. There is a significant drawback to this method: if you move a conversation out of the search folder into another folder, even the _sent_ emails are moved. I'll update the question with the caveat.

Comment: That only happens if you select the whole conversation, you can move just the latest email received to any folder and only it will be moved. On the other hand why not move the whole conversation with both sent and received into the "organized" folders?

Comment: The functionality varies from the Inbox, where the sent messages are not moved. As for the why not, it is personal preference. There are a number of reasons, but probably the biggest being that I expect to find all recently sent messages when I go to the Sent folder. I could again work around this with _yet another_ search folder, but that is definitely not ideal.

Comment: Is there an easy way to exclude calendar responses? I'm seeing my accept/reject messages too and these just get in the way.

Comment: Classic Microsoft "feature", being mistaken for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in Outlook 2010 and here is what I did.
[image: How it looks for me]

1. Under View-> conversations select "show as conversations
2. Under Conversations-> conversations settings check "show messages from other folders
3. **Under Arrangement-> view settings->sort-> select: received-> descending**
   [image: View Settings]

This will show all conversation in a string, deleted, sent and received.

Comment: #1 and #2 were already done. After changing #3, clicking an email in my inbox still shows my most recently _received_ message, even if a more recently _sent_ message exists.

Comment: Added screen shots

Comment: I see what you are getting at there. As mentioned, I can already see the sent items when the conversation is expanded. Regardless of the sort order, clicking the conversation displays the most recently _received_ email in the conversation in the _reading pane_. I have updated the question in an attempt to clarify for what I am looking.